# Create tables from SQL dump generated by phpmyadmin using kohana

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, kohana

I have a PHPMyAdmin SQL dump in a file. I want to use PHP to execute this SQL. How could I do that? I've tried a simple query (with Kohana but without it is enough too!) but I got a syntax error.
How could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Well this has nothing to do with Kohana. I would recommend you not do this through PHP as you then have memory and time constraints. If you can, use the terminal.

```
mysql -u [username] -p [password] [database name] < [filename.sql]
```

Replacing `[value]` with their respective values.

Comment: what if i am on shared hosting and cannot use shell

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = file_get_contents('sql_dump.sql');

mysql_query($sql);
```

I thought about using Kohana's `Db::query(Database::INSERT, $sql)->execute()`, but I'm not sure if it will work. Try it.

Comment: Nice and simple. Would this preserve line breaks too?

Comment: @Mark Steudel It should do :)

Comment: @thomas In what? The PHP or SQL?

Comment: @thomas There no reason why it shouldn't. I suggest you take [The Pixel Developer's advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433723/create-tables-from-sql-dump-generated-by-phpmyadmin-using-kohana/4441039#4441039) on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with The Pixel Developer. However, you could use PHP to initiate the command using [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec) Eg:

```
$result = shell_exec("mysql -h {$hostname} -u {$username} -p {$password} {$database} < $input_file");
```

Comment: what if i am on shred hosting and cannot use shell_exec()